# All vs There Exist

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

If one is asked a question such as "choose all forms of data that apply?", and in the options there exists possible anwsers that denote large groups of data sets, but only a subset of that large group could be applied, whould this be a correct answer.
Since the the question does not ask "choose all forms of data wherein there exists application?", nor "choose all forms of data that can always be applied?", I find myself confused by which whould be closer to the meaning of the question.

Comment: An example might help to clarify this... if you meant something like: given the question "_Which animals have long noses/nose-like appendages? Choose all that apply_" and one of the options was "_a. African mammals_" then I would say that _shouldn't_ be chosen, just because an elephant has a trunk. If you _wanted_ something like that to be included, you'd have to word the question along the lines of "_Which of these **includes** animals with..._".

Answer (score -1):

"Choose all forms of data that apply."  as given as a directive, idon't see anything logically or grammatically wrong with this.  the ending part of the sentence stipulates to choose ONLY what applies, and "all" expresses that there are possibly more than one answer that is applicable.

So, i think the first way you wrote it is perfect without the question mark.

Comment: The OP isn’t asking for proofreading.

Comment: That helps them out immensely Lawrence...

Comment: I cannot picture the possible/potential answers.  "Forms of data" is not clear.  Examples are needed.